# Changing modification time

Tags: c

I have my balanceModTime function that should set destination modification time to source modification time. The problem appears after calling this function, it sets modification time to Unknown in both files and sometimes set wrong dates in access time like 1989 etc.

```
void balanceModTime(char* destination, char* source) {
struct utimbuf sourceTime;
utime(source, &sourceTime);

struct utimbuf destinationTime;

destinationTime.modtime = sourceTime.modtime;
utime(destination, &destinationTime);
}
```

What causes the problem?

Comment: both `sourceTime` and `destinationTime` are used unitialized

Comment: " it sets modification time to Unknown in both files and sometimes set wrong dates in access time like 1989 " --> Yes that appears to be what this function is supposed to do - given the code.  Surely rather than using `utime()` to **set** the time of `source`, code should use a function (maybe `stat()`?) to **get** the time from the `source`.  Checking the return values of `utime()` would be a good addition too.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, you need to find the modification time of the source file via [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html), the access time of the destination file also using `stat()`, and use the (obsolescent) [`utime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html)
to set the modification and access times on the destination correctly.

That leads to code like:

```
/*b SO 4970-7519 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <utime.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s ref-file target-file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct stat sb_ref;
    if (stat(argv[1], &sb_ref) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to stat file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct stat sb_tgt;
    if (stat(argv[2], &sb_tgt) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to stat file %s\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct utimbuf ut = { .actime = sb_tgt.st_atime, .modtime = sb_ref.st_mtime };
    if (utime(argv[2], &ut) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to set modification time on %s\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to demonstrate that it works?  That's fiddlier than writing the code.
You'll probably need to use `ls -l` to see the modification times, and `ls -lu` to see the access times, possibly with `-T` to show the full time (in a most peculiar format on a Mac).  Alternatively, you could use the `stat` command — but they're not readily controlled (and the GNU and BSD/macOS versions are quite different).  I chose to also use a command I wrote called `fl` (file list) which allows me to control the information I see.

I used this script:

```
files="mt47.c get.jl.activity"
touch mt47.c
make mt47

echo;echo;echo
fl -F '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ' -am $files
ls -lT  $files
ls -luT $files
/usr/bin/stat $files
/opt/gnu/bin/stat $files

mt47 get.jl.activity mt47.c

echo;echo;echo
fl -F '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ' -am $files
ls -lT  $files
ls -luT $files
/usr/bin/stat $files
/opt/gnu/bin/stat $files
```

The result I got was:

```
gcc -O3   -g      -I./inc    -std=c11    -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes          -L./lib   mt47.c  -lsoq  -o mt47



2018-04-07 14:32:51  2018-04-07 14:32:51  mt47.c
2017-08-27 08:39:55  2017-03-03 17:06:27  get.jl.activity
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  173 Mar  3 17:06:27 2017 get.jl.activity
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  825 Apr  7 14:32:51 2018 mt47.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  173 Aug 27 08:39:55 2017 get.jl.activity
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  825 Apr  7 14:32:51 2018 mt47.c
16777220 8614148509 -rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler staff 0 825 "Apr  7 14:32:51 2018" "Apr  7 14:32:51 2018" "Apr  7 14:32:51 2018" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" 4194304 8 0 mt47.c
16777220 9176002 -rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler staff 0 173 "Aug 27 08:39:55 2017" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" "Jul 22 10:26:30 2017" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" 4194304 8 0 get.jl.activity
  File: mt47.c
  Size: 825         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
Device: 1000004h/16777220d  Inode: 8614148509  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/jleffler)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2018-04-07 14:32:51.478822831 -0700
Modify: 2018-04-07 14:32:51.301222000 -0700
Change: 2018-04-07 14:32:51.301240604 -0700
 Birth: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800
  File: get.jl.activity
  Size: 173         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
Device: 1000004h/16777220d  Inode: 9176002     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/jleffler)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2017-08-27 08:39:55.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800
Change: 2017-07-22 10:26:30.000000000 -0700
 Birth: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800



2018-04-07 14:32:51  2017-03-03 17:06:27  mt47.c
2017-08-27 08:39:55  2017-03-03 17:06:27  get.jl.activity
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  173 Mar  3 17:06:27 2017 get.jl.activity
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  825 Mar  3 17:06:27 2017 mt47.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  173 Aug 27 08:39:55 2017 get.jl.activity
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  825 Apr  7 14:32:51 2018 mt47.c
16777220 8614148509 -rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler staff 0 825 "Apr  7 14:32:51 2018" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" "Apr  7 14:32:51 2018" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" 4194304 8 0 mt47.c
16777220 9176002 -rw-r--r-- 1 jleffler staff 0 173 "Aug 27 08:39:55 2017" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" "Jul 22 10:26:30 2017" "Mar  3 17:06:27 2017" 4194304 8 0 get.jl.activity
  File: mt47.c
  Size: 825         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
Device: 1000004h/16777220d  Inode: 8614148509  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/jleffler)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2018-04-07 14:32:51.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800
Change: 2018-04-07 14:32:51.514236142 -0700
 Birth: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800
  File: get.jl.activity
  Size: 173         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4194304 regular file
Device: 1000004h/16777220d  Inode: 9176002     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/jleffler)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2017-08-27 08:39:55.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800
Change: 2017-07-22 10:26:30.000000000 -0700
 Birth: 2017-03-03 17:06:27.000000000 -0800
```

It demonstrates to my satisfaction that the code in `mt47.c` (which is shown above) does what I intend it to do.  It also shows me why I wrote `fl`.